# How to end an active call in skype

Tags: c#, skype

I am using the Skype API for video calling. Now I have a button to end the call. I wrote the following code on button's click:

```
if (skype.ActiveCalls.Count > 0)
{
    skype.ActiveCalls[0].Finish();

    //conference calls
    //for (int i = 0; i < skype.ActiveCalls.Count; i++)
    //{
        //if (skype.ActiveCalls[i + 1].ConferenceId > 0)
        //{
            //skype.ActiveCalls[i + 1].Finish();
            //call = skype.;
        //}
    //}
}
```

but it is throwing exception:

> Value does not fall within the expected range.

How to end an active call?

Comment: Well my guess from the commented code is that the ActiveCalls arrays is not zero based, and starts from 1, so you should change skype.ActiveCalls[0].Finish(); to skype.ActiveCalls[1].Finish(); Juat a guess

Comment: I will post this as the answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well my guess from the commented code

```
//conference calls 
//for (int i = 0; i < skype.ActiveCalls.Count; i++) 
//{ 
    //if (skype.ActiveCalls[i + 1].ConferenceId > 0) 
    //{ 
        //skype.ActiveCalls[i + 1].Finish(); 
        //call = skype.; 
    //} 
//}
```

is that the ActiveCalls arrays is not zero based, and starts from 1,

so you should change

`skype.ActiveCalls[0].Finish();`

to

```
skype.ActiveCalls[1].Finish();
```

Juat a guess